# Typedef uint8 x[4]

Tags: c, typedef

I found this line of code and I didn't understand how can you `typedef` a `uint8` to something that isn't a type in the first place like `x[4]`? 
What is really meant here ? Is it an just an array of 4 `uint8` type variables and that is just another way of saying it?

Code:

```
Typedef uint8 x[4]
```

Comment: This code compiles but gives error if I try to use the alias. Probably because the compiler defines the token as an alias. but this is an illegal keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of a `typedef` matches the syntax of a declaration. In this case, `x` is a type alias for `uint8[4]`.

Comment: I see now, thank you very much :)